# How do I title roles in a CV if I always was a contractor for my entire career?

Tags: job-search, resume, title

Been a contractor for 10 years. Writing my first formal CV. Targeting Google as senior SWE.

I purchased a CV review and got somewhat confusing recommendations regarding **Titles.**

Contractors have no titles, so, I wrote titles that best describe a given role.

**For instance:**
I designed and developed a large scale cloud native event-driven data processing architecture with dozens of GCP services involved.
I'm a certified GCP cloud architect.
I titled myself "System Architect, Data Engineer" for this role. The recruiter says that I should change it to "Senior SWE" since this is the role I'm targeting.

But AFAIK "Senior SWE" implies that there was a supervisor or a system architect who guided me. Right?

Comment: Why do you need to list titles? They're not universally recognized or consistent. Why not just list your certifications and experience?

Comment: Because recruiters love to use hierarchical terminology. It's more likely that you'll get a recruiter messaging you if your listed titles include senior. You'll get more junior/intermediate positions if the resume says junior everywhere.

Comment: "Contractors have no titles" - why do you think that??

Answer (score 6):

There is no globally-aligned job role description for software / IT industry - almost all the organisations follow their own nomenclature. Please use a title that best describes the job role, and the responsibilities that you handled at your work.

In other words, if you are asked to defend the title that you have used in the CV, you should be able to describe your accomplishments in line with the title.

If you do not have any single title suitable, and you have a certification that is closely linked with the job R&R (Roles and Responsibilities), you can use that certificate nomenclature, like the example in your question "Cloud Architect (GCP Certificated)".

Rest, does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

> But AFAIK "Senior SWE" implies that there was a supervisor or a system
> architect who guided me. Right?

Nothing is implied by that title. You could have been a SWE with more years of experience compared with the others. It could have meant that you were the person who supervised SWEs, even if they had more experience. It could have meant your were the only SWE.

Because there is no consensus regarding title the CV/resume has to describe what you did.

> Contractors have no titles, so, I wrote titles that best describe a
> given role.

Yes they do have titles. If you work for a company, and they rent your services to a client they are using a title when they market your services. Sometimes it is the title the company uses, sometimes it is the ones the client uses. I have always had a title for every company I have worked for, and every client I have supported.

If you are self-employed you must have been using something to explain the services you would provide.